# while trying to print the address of a[1] error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand pops up

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to print the address of the a[1] element. I know that it can be achieved by

`cout << a[i];`

but I just want to know why do I get the error message when I do this

`cout << &(a+1);`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[10];
    array[1]=3;
    cout<<"Address : "<<&(array+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe simply `a+1` ?

Comment: The assumption following the "I know that ..." is already wrong.

Comment: There is no address for something pointing to `array+1`.

Comment: [`std::cout << static_cast<void const*>(array+1) << '\n';`](https://ideone.com/s7P16M)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any array or pointer `a` and index `i`, the expression `a[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(a + i)`. From that we can draw the conclusion that `a + i` is a pointer which is equal to `&a[i]`.

So when you try to do `&(a + 1)` that's really equal to `&&a[1]` which makes no sense and gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Informally speaking, `array + 1` doesn't exist as a variable (you can't, for example, set it to another value), so you can't take the address of it. More formally an *lvalue* is required; i.e. something that can be set to a value.

Hence `&(array + 1)` emits a compilation error: in your case with some helpful hints.

Did you want simply `array + 1` for the address one beyond `array` in pointer arithmetic? In the evaluation of `array + 1`, `array` *decays* to an `int*` type.